# iOS Maintaing selected button in Tableview when scrolling

Tags: ios

I have a UItableView with custom cell. There are multiple sections, and in those sections multiple rows. In each cell, I have a segment button for "Yes" and "No" selections. I would like to maintain the selections for the segment button when I scroll up and down the table. Can anyone please help. I have looked and did not find anything that helped me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to do this.

The first one, which I think is the best one, is to use the selected state for the uitableviewcell. 
With this method, the table view it self will set the cell's state and according to that state will call didselect or diddeselect on its delegate. Since all is managed by the table view, you don't need additional logic on your cellForRow method, and don't even need to worry about cell reuse.

Another way is to always set the state of your cell's buttons in cellForRow. For this, you need to keep a reference to all the selected rows, and to be able to manage reused cells, you need to make sure its state is always set on cellForRow.

I prefer the first one, but whatever suits you better.

Comment: Thx Afonso, but I want to remember the selected segment button and not the cell itself. So how will the first method you mention help me? I have tried keeping track of the selected state with tag by assuaging the index row, but since I have multiple sections, the row index resets to 0 when a new sections is started. So buttons that I have not selected keep getting selected when i scroll. I am doing this in CellForRow.

Comment: So save the entire index path instead of just the row.

Comment: Actually, @CrimsonChris idea is what I would suggest. That or override the uitableviewcell's method prepareforreuse with the tag and the selected state. Still, I think it would be less overkill to save the indexpath.